# Connect LTE modem to RPi with systemd-networkd networking

Tags: networking, pi-3b+, modem, systemd-networkd, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I have a rpi3b+ running latest os as headless with everything up to date and I use systemd-networkd for networking on it. I'm trying to connect a LTE usb modem to it for wan access. For that I use mbim-utils. Upon starting network with mbim at `wwan0` with

```
#mbim-network /dev/cdc-wdm0 start
#mbimcli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 -p --query-ip-configuration                         (1)
```

its gives the ip address and gateway like

```
IP: x.x.x.x/y
Gateway: x.x.x.z                                                              (2)
```

Normally I'd manually up the interface and configure the IP and gateway to enable wan access as follows.

```
#ip link set dev wwan0 up
#ip addr add x.x.x.x/y dev wwan0
#ip addr route default via x.x.x.z dev wwan0                                  (3)
```

This works on my linux machine and the rpi as well. But I want to configure it with systemd-networkd. So tried by connecting the modem to its registered network with commands in block `(1)` and created a new network file at `/etc/systemd/network/wwan0.network` and put in the assigned static IP

```
[Match]
Name=wwan0
[Network]
Address=x.x.x.x/y
Gateway=x.x.x.z
IPForward=yes                                                                 (4)
```

and then restarted the `systemd-networkd.service`, but this didn't work as I couldn't ping any wan IPs. How to get wan access by configuring it with systemd-networkd?

Comment: What do `ip link` and `ip addr` say?

Comment: Please boot with the `wwan0.network` file and then add the output of the commands what *goldilocks* suggested and also from `systemctl status systemd-networkd.service`.